# Multiple worksheet with perl loop from array

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet

I was working with perl code to create a spreadsheet having multiple workshhets using **Spreadsheet::WriteExcel**. But the loop works only once and breaks. Please help to find what actually happening.

Code

```
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $workbook = new_workbook($r, 'Workbook.xls');
my $worksheet;
my @list = ('bike', 'car', 'bus');
foreach my $name (@list){
 $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($name);
 # writing excel data ...
}
$workbook->close();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If there are custom function calls in your example code, you should provide these functions, or at least a stub that explains that they are yours and what they do (like what you did inside the loop, actually). That will help others to understand that you know what you are doing. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the `$worksheet` variable outside of the loop (*1*) and then overwrite it in each loop iteration (*2*). That might lead to complications inside Spreadsheet::WriteExcel if the reference to the first worksheet suddently gets replaced with a new worksheet. Probably the XLS comes out with only the last worksheet.

```
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $workbook = new_workbook($r, 'Workbook.xls');
my $worksheet; # <--- 1
my @list = ('bike', 'car', 'bus');
foreach my $name (@list){
 $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($name); # <--- 2
 # writing excel data ...
}
$workbook->close();
```

Instead you should just declare a lexical `$worksheet` inside the loop where you use it. In general, allways declare variables in the smallest lexical scope in Perl.

```
foreach my $name (@list) {
  my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($name);
  # writing excel data ...
}
```